# Server 2003 answers ping, but wont serve http, ftp,smtp or pop3

Tags: windows-server-2003, smtp, service

After reboot, my server wont respond to any incoming request until it is rebooted again. Then, about 5-6 hrs later, any website on it will return a ping, but it will not serve the page, nor will it serve ftp, pop3 or smtp requests.

The System log shows W3SVC errors 1014 and 1074, which relate to an Application pool not replying; I have one phpAdmin app pool which I have stopped - it is showing a solitary website as the default App, but the server no longer serves php extensions, and I can't transfer the default website to another pool to kill the whole app pool.

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: We need to narrow down your problem a little bit and see whether this is a general network problem, an OS service problem, or just an IIS problem. You say that FTP and POP3 requests are also affected. Can you run a port scan or telnet to specific ports to verify whether FTP and POP3 are listening? Also, are there any services on Windows that should be running but are not?

Comment: I managed to eliminate the orphaned default app pool - there are no more app pool errors in the logs.  But the hangs still exist.  I tried ssh and the server won't accept the connection - it just sits there, doing nothing.  Ftp,Http, smtp and pop3 indicate they are connecting but eventually timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to pool hell.  If the application pool responsible for your sites isn't running... your site won't run.  As far as the default site goes, you probably need to configure it to run the php extensions.  If you don't really need the default site, you might simply need to stop it & start the correct sites.  I've seen similar situations where 2 sites are configured to both accept all server names on the same port/ip.

Comment: I managed to get rid of the app pool problems ( I think) - no more log messages.  The only app pool running now is the default app pool. php is gone. Still, at 6:40 am the server shutdown and re-started, and when it came up, it would not serve but it pings... I am puzzled

Answer (score 0):

Just because the server is pinging doesn't mean that the requisite services are.  (That just indicates that the server is running and the network stack is working.)

Have you verified that IIS (which covers WWW and FTP) is running, as well as your SMTP service?  You mention the IIS errors but don't mention whether those errors have stopped the service or not.

Comment: I am not located close tot he server, but it is sounding like I should take a trip to see it onsite the next time it hangs.

Comment: If you can RDP into it, do that.  Also, if you open an MMC under an account that has rights to that server, do so and open services and event viewer (or computer management to do it all at once) to check out the services and logs.

Comment: run nmap against it to see what ports it _is_ listening on.  That may help give you a clue what is working...

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this exact error before with no errors in the event log.  Completely puzzled for some time I did the following

Created a new site in IIS and left it under default config on a new IP on the machine.  No SSL either.  Just a blank page that says if it is working or not.

After rebooting the machine I found that the old problematic site still didn't work but the new site did.

Turns out it was some IIS problem where it was detecting port 80 was in use when it wasn't, and IIS would try to listen on the port and fail.  Or similarly there was an unused SSL port assigned to the site that wasn't needed that caused some issues and removing it/defining the ip settings on the sites cleared up the issue.

This may not be your exact problem but something I had found specifically on Windows 2003 with IIS very similar to your issues.

Answer (score 0):

With more than a little trepidation and after backing everything up, I un-installed IIS 6 and re-installed it  -  the configurations for about 30 websites on the server came back, but the problem went away, and the errors stopped appearing in the logs.  From what you say and what I found, it was definitely something gone astray in IIS.  Thanks for the closure.